# Firebase Storage security rules for folders

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am building an android app which has groups and Firebase storage has paths beginning with /{groupId}/Images/ and I have added security rules using file metadata. But the rules fail when I try to list contents of the Images folder because there is no metadata for a folder. How do I solve this issue?

Is there a way that I can access some random image from the Images folder in security rules and grant permission by looking at its metadata. Also, I can't use custom tokens because groupId is not known during sign up. Currently written security rules are as follows:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{groupId}/Images/{allPaths=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.metadata.keys() && groupId in resource.metadata.keys();
          allow write: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.metadata.keys() && groupId in request.resource.metadata.keys();
            
    }
  }
}
```

The code where these rules fail is:

```js
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
StorageReference listRef = storageReference.child(groupId).child("Images");

listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
           for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Storage reference prefix is: "+prefix);
           }

           for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Storage reference item is: "+item);
           }
      }
      })
      .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               Log.w(TAG, "listRef on storage failed: ",e);
           }
      });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal rules and code with which we can reproduce the problem. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is this fine now?

Comment: Thanks for that. Now can you also show the code that is failing when you run it against these rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done

Answer (score 0):

When you request a file listing, the security rules are not going to check every file to determine whether to include it in the results, as that would not perform well.

Instead security rules are statically evaluated when the request comes in. They check the request against the rules to see if the request might ever return something that the rules don't allow.

In your code, since you're requesting all files, the request will be rejected. If you'd be getting one specific file, the rules are able to check the metadata on that file and can securely grant/deny access to it.

On Firestore and the Realtime Database you can combine using a query in your code with rules that then check the query conditions, and securely query data in that way. But since you can't perform queries on Cloud Storage, you can't use this approach in store.

So for file listings, as far as I can see, the only security you can reasonable add is on the path of the files. If you want something more, I'd recommend replicating the metadata in a database that allows the query, and securely query it there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frank. But how will metadata replication in Firestore/ Realtime Database ensure that no one except group member can list the contents of Images folder? And also, in the worst case, if I cannot add any security for a folder in this case, how should security rules be modified to allow list functionality to work.

Comment: You'd disable listing file in Storage altogether in that case. Before v2 that was actually the only option, as there was no way to list files through the Firebase SDK.